# Sending and Retrieving data from server - Windows 8 Program

Tags: javascript, html, windows

I am developing a program in windows 8 using JavaScript, HTML5 and CSS. I am making a chat system for my school, and I was wondering if there is a way to send a login request to a server to verify details.

Comment: Well yes there are ways to do just that.

Comment: @PeeHaa My question states if anyone knows how?

Comment: Well yes somebody knows how.